# How to remove sub-array from 2d array?

Tags: javascript, splice

Below I have a simple two dimensional array. If I want to remove the whole sub-array where index 0 of the sub array is equal to Susie, how would I do this?

```
var array1 = [["Ben", 17, 1], ["Susie", 12, 0], ["Thomas", 21, 1]];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can traverse through the array and find the index and then do a splice.

```
var array1 = [["Ben", 17, 1], ["Susie", 12, 0], ["Thomas", 21, 1]];
console.log(array1);

for(var x=0; x<array1.length; x++) {

    if(array1[x][0] == "Susie")
        array1.splice(x,1);

}

console.log(array1);
```

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/qMFHX/) is a fiddle.

Comment: Although both answers do the job, I prefer this answer as I can understand exactly what it is doing. Thanks!

Comment: just in case you're interested: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter a short reference on the 'filter' method.

Answer (score 1):

```
var initialArray = [["Ben", 17, 1], ["Susie", 12, 0], ["Thomas", 21, 1]];
var subArray = initialArray.filter(function(item) { return item[0] != 'Susie'; });
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XHEJt/1/